# Artifactory OSS 6.5.2 - can't connect to the UI from servers on the network

Tags: web-services, artifactory

I have recently installed Artifactory OSS 6.5.2 on a remote server in our network which runs on windows server 2012.

I can enter the UI locally (the machine running the Artifactory instance) through any of the browsers with this address:
"http://{local-ip}:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/"

When I try entering the UI from one of the machines on the network I get a "This site can’t be reached" message after multiple attempts to connect.

The request.log at {ARTIFACTORY_HOME}\logs\request.log shows that the request got through and succeeded:

```
"REQUEST|{remote-ip}|anonymous|GET|/webapp/|HTTP/1.1|200|0"
```

The same is showed for requests coming from the server running the Artifactory instance:

```
"REQUEST|{local-ip}|anonymous|GET|/webapp/|HTTP/1.1|200|0"
```

However, in contrary to the previous request from a remote machine, the initial request is followed by more requests:

```
"REQUEST|{local-ip}|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/screen/footer|HTTP/1.1|200|0

 REQUEST|{local-ip}|anonymous|GET|/ui/treebrowser/repoOrder|HTTP/1.1|200|0

 REQUEST|{local-ip}|anonymous|GET|/ui/onboarding/initStatus|HTTP/1.1|200|0

 REQUEST|{local-ip}|anonymous|GET|/ui/auth/current|HTTP/1.1|200|0"
```

I thought maybe there is an automatic redirection that uses 'localhost' instead of the ip or hostname so I tried changing the {ARTIFACTORY_HOME}\tomcat\conf\server.xml:

```
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8081" sendReasonPhrase="true" relaxedPathChars='[]' relaxedQueryChars='[]'/>

    <!-- Must be at least the value of artifactory.access.client.max.connections -->
    <Connector port="8040" sendReasonPhrase="true" maxThreads="50"/>

    <!-- This is the optional AJP connector -->
    <Connector port="8019" protocol="AJP/1.3" sendReasonPhrase="true"/>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host **name="localhost" -> name="{hostname}** appBase="webapps" startStopThreads="2"/>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

But then the Artifactory failed to initialize:

> "[art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.ArtifactoryAccessClientConfigStore:643) -
>   Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8040/access (bundled)
>   source: detected
>
> [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:308) - Waiting for
>   access server...
>
> [art-init] [WARN ] (o.j.a.c.AccessClientHttpException:41) -
>   Unrecognized ErrorsModel by Access. Original message: Failed on
>   executing /api/v1/system/ping, with response: Not Found"

I did not set any proxies or reverse proxies as I don't think it's related, but I may be mistaken as I don't have a lot of experience with web services.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thnx,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

I was deploying artifactory 6 via helm, then upgraded to 6.8.2 and ran into this.

had to

```
cd $ARTIFACTORY_HOME &&  chown -R artifactory:artifactory .
```

artifactory itself, on startup, seemed not to be able to deploy the access.war and then maybe also was not able to read the credentials it needed to hit this /access context health check "ping" api endpoint.

Comment: Thnx for taking the time to answer. Because no solution was found in time, the Artifactory was installed on a different machine and the issue did not return. The cause for the issue is still unknown so I will keep your solution in mind, in case of a future encounter.